# MS Sync 2.1 Sync tables with foreig keys

Tags: .net, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

is it possible to have in a synchronization scope, 2 tables that have a foreign key associated.

I receive a strange message in the `_tracking table: Column 'TransactionLineNo' is constrained to be unique.  Value '582da05c-2341-4c57-9795-b532ee0e596f' is already present.`

`TransactionLineNo` is the primary key in my table (TransactionLine) and has a foreign key to Transaction table which is added in the same scope.
I am using MS Sync 2.1
Angela

Comment: would you know which tracking table its failing? Transaction or TransactionLine table?

Answer (score 1):

It is important that your SyncAdapters be defined and added to the SyncProvider's adapter collection in order of Grandparent, Parent, Child etc. or you can get behavior like what you are seeing.  Make sure that Transaction's adapter was added to the server's SyncProvider before TransactionLine.

In the past, I have written a SQL stored procedure using INFORMATION_SCHEMA to query and programmatically determine the order to build the adapters, which has worked out pretty well for us so far (the MSDN on INFORMATION_SCHEMA is available here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx).

Also, if you are debugging a partially completed application and adding values via synchronization and into the database directly, it is possible to get the Sync Anchors used on the client and server out of sync and this error could be resolved in some instances by just dropping and recreating the client database.

Comment: she's using a different database provider and working with scopes rather than sync groups.